# AttributeError at /print/8 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm trying to print the item in python-django by "ReportLab PDF" and i have an error like this:

*AttributeError at /print/8 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'*

Below here are important codes

models.py

```
class Games(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    type = models.ForeignKey("Types")
    date_of_production = models.DateField()
    producer = models.ForeignKey("Producers")
    availability = models.BooleanField()
    account = models.IntegerField()
    language = models.ForeignKey("Languages", default='')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class GamesForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label= "Nazwa gry", max_length=50)
    type = forms.CharField(label= "Typ gry", max_length=10)
    date_of_production = forms.DateField(label= "Data produkcji")
    producer = forms.CharField(label= "Nazwa producenta", max_length= 10)
    availability = forms.BooleanField(label= "Czy jest dostępne?")
    account = forms.IntegerField(label= "Ilość dostępnych sztuk")
    language = forms.CharField(label= "Języki", max_length=50)
    price = forms.CharField(label= "Cena", max_length=10)
    abbr = forms.CharField(label= "Skrót waluty", max_length=5)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect 
from django.http import Http404
import datetime
from .forms import *
from .models import Games
from .models import Producers
from .models import Types
from .models import Languages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def printgame (request,id):
    #try:
        game = Games.objects.get(pk=id)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Deposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'


        page = canvas.Canvas(response)
        page.setLineWidth(.3)
        page.setFont('Verdana', 12)

        page.drawString(30,750, "Wydruk gry: ")
        page.drawString(30,700, "Tytuł gry: ")
        page.drawString(100,700, game.title )
        page.drawString(30,650, "Typ gry: ")
        page.drawString(130,650, game.type)
        page.drawString(30,600, "Data produkcji: ")
       #page.drawString(150,600, game.date_of_production)
        page.drawString(30,550, "Dostępność: ")
       #page.drawString(130,550, game.availability)
        page.drawString(30,500, "Ilość: ")
        page.drawString(130,500, game.account)
        page.drawString(30,450, "Język: ")
        page.drawString(130,450, game.language)
        page.drawString(30,400, "Cena: ")
        page.drawString(130,400, game.price)
        page.drawString(30,350, "Skrót waluty: ")
        page.drawString(130,350, game.abbr)

        page.line(30, 325, 300, 325)

        page.drawString(30,250, "Dane techniczne ")
        page.drawString(30,200, "ID gry:")
        page.drawString(200,200, id)

        page.showPage()
        page.save()

        return response
```

list.html

```
<h1>Lista gier</h1>

<table border=1>
     <tr>
     <th>Nazwa gry</th>
     <th>Typ gry</th>
     <th>Data produkcji</th>
     <th>Nazwa producenta</th>
     <th>Czy jest dostępne?</th>
     <th>Ilość dostępnych sztuk</th>
     <th>Języki</th>
     <th>Cena</th>
     <th>Skrót waluty</th>
     <th>Edycja</th>
     <th>Usuwanie</th>
     <th>Druk PDF</th>
     </tr>

     {% for Games in all_games %}

     <tr>
     <th><a href="/view/{{Games.id}}">{{Games.title}}</a></th>
     <th>{{Games.type}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.date_of_production}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.producer}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.availability}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.account}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.language}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.price}}</th>
     <th>{{Games.abbr}}</th>
     <td><a href="/edit/{{Games.id}}">Edycja</td>
     <td><a href="/delete/{{Games.id}}">Usuń</td>
     <td><a href="/print/{{Games.id}}">PDF</td>
     </tr>

      {% endfor %}
 </table>

 <a href="/new/">Nowa gra</a>

{% endblock %}
```

new.html

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}
{% block  content %}

<h1>Nowa gra</h1>

   <form action="/new/" method="post">

   {% csrf_token %}

   Nazwa gry:
   <input type="text" name="title"> </input></br>
   Typ gry:
   <input type="text" name="type"> </input></br>
   Data produkcji:
   <input type="date" name="date_of_production"> </input></br>
   Nazwa producenta:
   <input type="text" name="producer"> </input></br>
   Czy jest dostępne?
   <input type="checkbox" name="availability"> </input></br>
   Ilość dostępnych sztuk:
   <input type="number" name="account"> </input></br>
   Języki:
   <input type="text" name="language"> </input></br>
   Cena:
   <input type="number" name="price"> </input></br>
   Skrót waluty:
   <input type="text" name="abbr"> </input></br>

   <input type="submit" value="Dodaj"></input>

   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

After launching this website it shows line error:

```
page.drawString(130,450, game.account)
```

I want to show account of games. But i don't know what and how to do this. Any Ideas? Thx for every advice

Comment: You should reduce your code to what is related to the problem and instead post your full error trace back.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Emphasis on **Minimal**. Furthermore, you should tell us what efforts you have undertaken so far in order to fix this error. We are not your debugger.